# Compiler error on if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding/scripting. Its a school project, I would have to change the below code to add `Application.EnableEvents` to the existing code to suppress the Change event in other macros.

I tried to change the code, but I get a compile error else without if. I validated the syntax, it looks OK. What am I doing wrong here? Is my understanding with "IF" statements not correct?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E43")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("E44")
            If Target.Value = "Specific number of Days" Then
                .Locked = False
                .Activate
            Else
                'This handles **ANY** other value in the dropdown
                .Locked = True
                '.Clear
            End If
        End With
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E30")) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value = "YES" Then Call Class8 Else Call Class8User
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E31")) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value = "YES" Then Call Class7 Else Call Class7User
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am trying to change the code as below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E43")) Is Nothing Then
    With Range("E44")
        If Target.Value = "Specific number of Days" Then
            .Locked = False
            .Activate
        Else
            'This handles **ANY** other value in the dropdown
            .Locked = True
            '.Clear
        End If
    End With
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E30")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Notify
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call NotifyUser
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E31")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Delta
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call DeltaUser
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Comment: You are missing `End If` after the `Application.EnableEvents = True` in each of the `ElseIf` blocks. You would see that visually if you followed standard code indentation practices.

Answer (score 1):

Always indent all your code - then you can easily see where you are missing the `end if`

```
Private Sub x(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E43")) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("E44")
            If Target.Value = "Specific number of Days" Then
                .Locked = False
                .Activate
            Else
                'This handles **ANY** other value in the dropdown
                .Locked = True
                '.Clear
            End If
        End With
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E30")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call notify
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call notifyuser
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If     ' <-- This was missing
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E31")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call delta
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call deltaUser
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If     ' <-- This was missing
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```